# Head hunters/job search sites for Mathematicians?

Tags: career-development

What are good job search sites, head hunter/recruiting agencies for mathematicians looking for industry jobs?

If this question is not appropriate for the math stack exchange, please feel free to redirect me.

Comment: By mathematician, do you mean a person with an undergraduate degree or a person with a Ph.D.?

Comment: @Potato I am thinking of PHD, but if you have ones for undergrads I dont mind

Comment: Natural starting point: http://www.siam.org/careers/

Comment: @Amr Are you a graduate student, or you possess a Ph.D.?

Comment: (If you are a graduate student, I think the best idea is to talk to you advisor or professors in your department who work in applied mathematics about job opportunities.)

Comment: @Potato No. I don't even have a math degree. I am just very intrested to know

Comment: @Potato Research jobs for mathematicians in biology, physics, ... count as well. I prefer if these jobs are not related to statistics or numerical analysis

Comment: @Amr If you are looking for job advice relevant to your situation, you might want to open a new question with more context. It's very hard to give advice with no information.

Comment: @Potato Thanks for our help. I have been hearing a lot that most of math does not have applications .... Thus, I wanted to see what mathematicians do outside academia and pure math research. I realize that advanced math areas for non-mathematicians ( abstract algebra, algebraic geometry,..) have real world applications. However, I think that one the application is found by a mathematician it is being applied by non-mathematicians. I want to see jobs where you go and look for mathematicians. Do you think I should put this as another question ?

Comment: @Amr I think so. You may also be interested in these questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105495/what-can-an-algebraic-geometer-do-outside-academia

Comment: It seems that only mathematicians think about siam.org -- I rarely see posts for jobs/careers there that are outside of academia

Answer (score 18):

I think you are going to find a mixed bag of things on this topic as it is rather broad from school teachers, to professors to researchers to applied math jobs and the like.=, up to and including engineering.

For example, [*Top Paying Math Careers*](http://www.investopedia.com/financial-edge/0812/top-paying-math-related-careers.aspx).

Here is a sampling for some ideas and sites to look at for conferences and contacts regarding math, head hunters, sites, et. al..

- [*MAA Math Classifieds*](http://www.mathclassifieds.org/home/home.cfm?site_id=1925)
- [*indeed*](http://www.indeed.com/q-Mathematics-l-Charlotte,-NC-jobs.html)
- [*DW Simpson - Actuaries*](http://www.dwsimpson.com/)
- [*National Financial Mathematics Career Fair*](http://www.finmathjobfair.org/)
- [*How to get a job - PH.D's*](http://www.phds.org/jobs/how-to-get-a-job/)
- [*Financial Mathematics Job Resources*](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~nichols/Financial_Mathematics_Job_Resources.html)
- [*Math Teacher Jobs*](http://mathematics.teacher.jobs.topusajobs.com/)
- [*Math Employers*](http://www.salisbury.edu/careerservices/Students/MajorsEmployers/Math.html)
- [*Simply Hired - Applied Math*](http://www.simplyhired.com/a/jobs/list/q-applied+mathematics)

More specialized fields are also possible in research and the financial sector and the schools big in those areas can provide further support and resources in those cases.

Comment: Great list, Amzoti. I will save as a favorit +1

Comment: @amWhy: I wish someone would think it worthwhile to create an all-encompassing job site for math majors and all the different types of careers that hire them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Careers in Mathematics](https://math.uwaterloo.ca/math/future-undergraduates/careers-mathematics) would be a page from the University of Waterloo in Canada that has a Faculty of Mathematics that covers various disciplines including Actuarial Science, Operations Research, and Computer Science in addition to conventional branches of Mathematics like Pure Math, Applied Math, Accounting and Statistics noting various career options as there can be more than a few things that may fall under the heading of a Mathematician.  This isn't exactly what was asked though it is pretty close to what one could do with a Math degree which I could see as a way to know who are Mathematicians in the world.