# Using math to help people

Tags: education, career-development

So I am currently a graduate student at the University of Colorado. I love math. From calculus to category theory to everything in between, I have tried and, for the most part, loved it. However, I also feel like it is important to help other people (particularly those less privileged.) My first thought was to work somehow with the World Bank  in some kind of applied math capacity, but I thought I would ask people here, what kinds of jobs can a mathematician aim for that will help other people, especially the poor? Thanks!!
-DJ

Comment: [Our most upvoted question of all time](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/71874/8173) might be helpful.

Comment: You can teach math to poor people in your own country, I think it's a good start.

Comment: Poor people stink, so bring nose plugs.

Answer (score 1):

Go teach in Somalia. It's a wonderful place that welcomes Americans. Teach the unfortunate in their natural habitat.